# Is it safe to init a Mercurial repository on /etc?

Tags: etc, mercurial, configuration-management

My company has an external server, mostly managed by a 3rd party. Sometimes they do configuration changes but 'forgot' to tell us.

I am thinking of tracking all changes to `/etc`. Is it safe to do `hg init` in `/etc`?

(I can then create a cronjob to run every 5 or 10 minutes, doing `hg addremove && hg commit`).

Answer (score 4):

I would say "Yes!" and redirect you to [`etckeeper`](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/etckeeper.html).

Even though the LTS server guide uses `bzr`, `etckeeper` is more versatile. From [`man etckeeper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/etckeeper):

```
etckeeper - store /etc in git, mercurial, bazaar, or darcs
```

I personally use it with `git`. `etckeeper` will set up a repository when you install it, if it finds that `/etc/` is not under version control, and use `bzr` by default. So create `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` before hand, and set Mercurial as the preferred VCS system:

```
VCS="hg"
```

There are other variables set in that configuration file, so you might want to test it out on a system and then copy over the configuration.

Comment: Whoa, thanks! I never heard of `etckeeper` before, sounds exactly what I need!